# how to use iostream to pipe between programs? c++

Tags: c++

So in my school assignment, I've been given a skeleton program. The program can be run in both server mode and client mode.

```
When run in server mode the program takes input from std::cin and outputs to std::cout
When run in client mode the program takes input from std::cin and outputs to std::cout
```

What i want to do is pipe them together using C++ code, (though I'm also asking how to pipe them in "Windows" using named pipes in another question)

So i was thinking something like:

```
std::iostream server_input_client_output, server_output_client_input
start server in a thread Server(server_input_client_output, server_output_client_input)
start client in main thread Client(server_output_client_input, server_input_client_output)
```

I do not want to rewrite the entire skeleton program, i simply want to give the Server and Client valid inputs that allow bidirectional realtime communication.

Anyone know? Thanks.

Comment: http://pstreams.sf.net/ -- on a real OS you create a pipe, fork, redirect input (or output as appropriate) to one end of the pipe, then exec the new program. That's basically what the shell does to create a pipeline. On Windows it's trickier. There is a branch with partial Windows support in the old CVS repo for Pstreams, but I have no idea if it works, I didn't write the Windows support

Comment: Just a small question, why making your program limited by using it with pipes. If its just skeleton so make socks for communication.. I am not sure if you have some reason for direct communication.

Comment: forgot to mention that if you are using socks then you can later extend your program... Scalability wise also its better...

Comment: Because that's what the professor asked for. Note this is not an answer, you need to post this as a comment.

Comment: well i was hoping for an easier solution that required less work. but i suppose i could find some time to write it using sockets. the teacher will most certainly assign me future assignments like this. thanks for the comments people.